# Problems with basic usage of saltstack apache-formula

Tags: salt-stack

I'm new to Saltstack and I'm just trying to do some simple installs on a subset of minions. I want to include Environments so I have my file roots as:

```
file_roots:
   base:
     - /srv/salt/base
   dev:
     - /srv/salt/dev
   qa:
     - /srv/salt/qa
   stage:
     - /srv/salt/stage
   prod:
     - /srv/salt/prod
```

I set up the git backend:

```
fileserver_backend:
  - git
  - roots
```

I'm using gitfs set as:

```
gitfs_remotes:
  - https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/postgres-formula
  - https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/apache-formula
  - https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/memcached-formula
  - https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/redis-formula
```

So I have the master set up and I add top.sls to /srv/salt/stage with

```
include:
   - apache
stage:
   'stage01*':
      - apache
```

But I get an error when I execute

```
salt -l debug \* state.highstate test=True
```

Error

```
stage01.example.net:
Data failed to compile:
----------
No matching sls found for 'apache' in env 'stage'
```

I've tried many ways and the master just can't seem to find the apache formula I configured for it.

Comment: Did you install the dependency pygit2 as described here https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/file_server/all/salt.fileserver.gitfs.html?

Comment: Yes. I did run into that problem with the missing dependency but sorted that out before I had this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer and it was sitting in the Saltstack docs the whole time.

1. First you will need to fork the current repository such as postgres-formula.
2. Depending on the environment create a branch of the same name in your newly create fork of the repo.

So for example I wanted to use postgres in my **stage** environment. So it wouldn't work until I created a branch named **stage** ined my forked repo of postgres-formula then it worked like a charm.